# laravel call to undefined method Auth guard

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-authorization

i want to prevent the login after register in Laravel 5.5, I already did this by commenting a line:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    //    $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

i override it in RegisterController.php

i got this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::guard()
    $guard = array_get($exception->guard(),0);
    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            return redirect()->guest(route('admin.login'));
            break;

        default:
            return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
            break;
    }
```

Here is the content of my config/auth:

```
<?php

return [



    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],



    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],



    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],


    ],



    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

i have enabled multi-auth system which is i have an admin login and a user login, what i wan't is to disable the login after register in my user page.

Comment: post the contents of your `config/auth.php`

Comment: @SapneshNaik hello sir i posted my config/auth please help thanks

Comment: @SapneshNaik why is it error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check guard in the exception can do something like this:

```
return redirect(route(auth()->guard('admin')->check() ? 'admin.login' : 'login'));
```

Also, use `auth()` helper or `Auth::` facade in the `RegisterController@register` if you're trying to override the method:

```
auth()->guard('admin')->login($user);
```

Comment: hi @Alexey because i make it multi-auth system with admin. Where would i change this?. please help thanks

Comment: still error, i put the first line in unauthenticated and override the auth()->guard('admin')->login($user); in registerController

Comment: @JcJohn and what about exception? Have you tried the code for exception?

Comment: @JcJohn you're using this code in an exception? Have you tried to use the code from my answer (the first part of it)?